# Get a Join on Two Dictionaries with different Datatypes in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, namely

```
Dictionary<string,string> DictA=new Dictionary<string,string>();
Dictionary<string,int> DictB=new Dictionary<string,int>();
DictA.Add("A","A1");
DictA.Add("B","B1");
DictA.Add("C","C1");

DictB.Add("A",10);
DictB.Add("B",20);
DictB.Add("K",30);
```

Now I need to form a Third dictionary like this.

```
<10,A1>
<20,B1>
```

I am pretty much sure this is doable with operations on Dictionaries or Lambda Expressions but not sure on how to achieve this.

Comment: I doubt you have wrote this code in VS and compiled it... Can you please correct it, my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: @Sharped: I was more focused on the Idea than on the Syntax while posting this..hope I got it right now. sorry about that

Comment: Did you really mean to get `<10, A>` or did you actually want `<10, A1>`?

Answer (score 3):

```
DictA.Join(DictB, 
           a => a.Key,
           b => b.Key,
           (a,b) => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(b.Value,a.Key))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from his question whether or not he intends the result to be `Dictionary<int, string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>` - this produces the latter, if he's after the former he'd need to convert (or try to) `x.Key` to an `int` in the `ToDictionary` invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
var query =
    DictA
        .Where(a => DictB.ContainsKey(a.Key))
        .ToDictionary(a => DictB[a.Key], a => a.Value);
```

I get this result:

[image: result]